# NUnit3.TestAdapter Installation Issue

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, visual-studio-2019, nunit-3.0

I have installed the NUnit3TestAdapter in several .net Core 3.1 test projects. The projects uses PackageReference in the .csproj file so I thought the dlls were supposed to be stored in a global %USERPROFILE%.nuget\packages directory.

Instead, I see the dlls stored in the root directory of the project, which looks a bit messy.

Is this an installation bug?

[image]

Comment: Did you see those files in the project root directory in Windows Explorer? If not, then what you observed is just the illusion created by VS Solution Explorer (which is not uncommon).

Comment: No, the files do not exist in the directory. I have not seen this before except in this particular instance. Very strange.